# Pre-action before visual studio update

Tags: visual-studio

I need to close a certain program before I perform a Visual Studio update. Without going into the specifics of why, is there is a way to remind me when ever I'm about to perform a Visual Studio update? I do have a command line to stop this program, I'm wondering if there's some kind of pre-hook. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think such "trigger" exists in VS. Maybe write a script that continuously checks if the `vs_installershell` process is running and either remind you or kill the process of the other program automatically?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.